# transform array of object shape into different array block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I transform this structure

```
const arr = [
  {
    "name": "a_1",
    "v": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "b_1",
    "v": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "a_2",
    "v": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "b_2",
    "v": 3
  }
]
```

to this?

```
[{
  a: 1,
  b: 1
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: 3
}]
```

Tried forEach, and used split('_').pop() to get the group key of the name but stuck in grouping them together.

Comment: I'd initially misunderstood your desired output, sorry. Correcting myself, I'd suggest [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). That said, my point still stands; you're likely to get better answers and a better response overall if you provide your attempt(s).

Comment: Are they gonna be in same order? Should It also work if input array is in a_1, a_2,b_1, b_2 order?

Comment: So many edge cases to consider. I feel like there is a deeper underlying question that would make this problem unnecessary. What if you had `a_42` after your test set? What if the ordering was strange? Could `a_2` exist in multiple items? Most importantly, **why** do you feel you need this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this would be to `reduce()` the input array to build a `map` object which temporarily stores a "key/value" relation between the number after the underscore (key) and "v" number (value). The required result would then be obtained by extracting a value array from the `map` object via `Object.values()`:

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "a_1",
    "v": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "b_1",
    "v": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "a_2",
    "v": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "b_2",
    "v": 3
  }
];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((map, item, index) => {

  // Extract data from current item of arr
  const { name, v } = item;
  
  // Break name to letter and key string parts
  const [letter, key] = name.split("_");

  // Obtain current obj for key from mapping
  // or create empty object for new key
  const obj = map[key] || {}

  // Update letter with v for current obj
  obj[letter] = v;

  // Update mapping with updated key/obj
  return {...map, [key] : obj };

}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your array order remains same, you can try this recursive solution

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "a_1",
    v: 1
  },
  {
    name: "b_1",
    v: 1
  },
  {
    name: "a_2",
    v: 2
  },
  {
    name: "b_2",
    v: 3
  }
];


const finalArr = []
function reduce(arr){
    if(arr.length === 0){
        return;
    }
    const [one, two] = arr;
    finalArr.push({[one.name.split("_")[0]]: one.v, [two.name.split("_")[0]]: two.v});
    reduce(arr.slice(2))
}
reduce(arr);
console.log(finalArr);
```